# matlab compiled program execute code on close

Tags: matlab, compiled

I have a compiled matlab program that runs as a dos box basically (ie no GUI). Is there a way to get code to execute when someone closes the program? Specifically closing by clicking on the X?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to define a [cleanup task](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/oncleanup.html). This will be executed whenever a function is terminated (by whatever means), so as long as closing the program is not done with a `kill -9` command or similar, the code is being run.